# Can I replace an ATA 2.5" HDD with a SATA 2.5" HDD in a laptop?

Tags: hard-drive, laptop, sata, connector, ata

Are there any connectors available that would allow me to replace an ATA 2.5" hard drive with a SATA 2.5" hard drive in a laptop?

Needless to say, it must be slim enough to fit.

I am aware that it won't get SATA speeds, but this is not important. I just want to connect SATA because I have a newer and bigger drive, and a need for more free space.

Answer (score 8):

There are PATA to SATA adapters, but I wouldn't expect any to fit within the confines of a laptop HDD cavity.